# Product Repository Error White Screen

Tags: magento2.4

I am creating a module and this is code in my blocks PHP file. I get a white screen when I try to access ProductRepository. `$this->_productRepository`. There is no error in logs are anywhere. Only white screen. Need an extra set of eyes to find the error. Thanks

```
<?php
namespace CD\BulkChildPriceUpdate\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab;

use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use \Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Api\LinkManagementInterface;
use \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use \Magento\Framework\Registry;
use \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;

class ChildProducts extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    protected $_template = 'childproducts.phtml';
    protected $_productRepository;
    protected $_searchCriteriaBuilder;
    protected $_linkManagement;
    protected $_registry = null;

    public function __construct(
        LinkManagementInterface $linkManagement,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        Registry $registry,
        Context $context, 
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->_linkManagement = $linkManagement;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_registry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return $this->_registry->registry('current_product');
    }
    public function getChilds() 
    {
      $parentId = $this->_registry->registry('current_product')->getId();
      $searchCriteria = $this->_searchCriteriaBuilder
            ->addFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
            ->addFilter('entity_id', $parentId)
            ->create();

            return $this->_productRepository;
//     try{
//         $configurableProducts = $this->productRepository->getList($searchCriteria);
//     }catch(\Exception $e){
//         return $e->getMessage();
//     }

// return $configurableProducts;

//       foreach ($configurableProducts->getItems() as $configurableProduct) {
//         $childProducts = $this->linkManagement
//             ->getChildren($configurableProduct->getSku());
//       }
//       return $childProducts;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In phtml file, I was doing `var_dump` returned products. I removed the var_dump and page started loading.

Comment: Yeah, many Magento objects have recursive reference loops, so var_dump-ing them will be infinite.

Comment: You can use a custom function similar to var_dump to get some of the debugging info you need without recursing infinitely: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23833235/in-php-can-a-var-dump-be-done-on-an-object-without-including-the-dump-of-obje

Comment: @mysterious Don't ever try to `var_dump` or `print_r` any Class/Object in Magento, there's `->getData()` for that!

Answer (score 0):

In the _productRepository variable, you just declared it above and it is not called to handle getting data anywhere. So when you return $this->_productRepository it will just return an empty data and that's the cause of your error.